# how to embed external xml with fla & publish them as a single swf file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

so recently i finished making a quiz with flash CS6 that loads questions from an external XML file ,but now i need to merge the .fla file with the external xml & publish them as a single swf file & as simple as it sounds i couldn't figure the right way to do this .

here is my xml loader:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
loader.load(new URLRequest("quiz.xml"));
```

im a total beginner when it comes to using xml , so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use an `XML` object to store your XML content : `var xml:XML =  <data><!-- .. --></data>;` ... For more about working with XML, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html) ...

Comment: Use `[embed]` to combine the XML file & output SWF as one file.